# Extrapolate using specific function of past values and predicted from regression

Tags: r, na, prediction, lag

i have a panel with different states and years,  and  some of the final  years missing, like  this:

```
require(data.table)
comb1 <- cbind(CJ(letters[1:4], 2000:2019), rnorm(80,2,1)) 
comb1 <- cbind(comb1, round(runif(n=20, min=1, max=20), 0))
comb2 <-  cbind(CJ(letters[1:4], 2020:2024), data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 20, ncol = 2)))
colnames(comb1) <- c("state","year","v","z")
colnames(comb2) <- c("state","year","v","z")

comb <- rbind(comb1, comb2)
comb <- comb[order(comb$state, comb$year),]
```

I need to fill NA  values such that, for one variable would be combination of previous  three years as:
`v[year] <- v[year-1]*0.5 + v[year-2]*0.2 + v[year-3]*0.3`

and other  variable would be predicted value from linear  model:
`lm(z~year)`.

Could be in data.frame  or data.table  whatever is more  simple to implement..  Thank you for help!!!